# is there anyway to delete the properties from object which are defined using Object.defineProperty()?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am just curious to know that, is there anyway to delete properties from an object defined using Object.defineProperty().

I have gone through the MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) docs, I didn't find any clue to delete the properties.

Comment: Yes, `delete obj.property`.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete them like any other property, with [**`delete`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), but *only* if they are defined with `configurable: true`:

> configurable
>       `true` if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
>       Defaults to `false`.

If not, they cannot be deleted.